# Please tell how this whole mesh is modelled...?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

---

[image]

I am not able to understand how this shape has been modelled. I really need to learn this.. please help.

Comment: Don't understand the question. You seem to have the mesh so can't you just look at it in edit mode? What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

1. Make a cylinder.
2. Make two loop cuts per paddle. I just start with two loop cuts overall and will do the others later. (`STRG+R`)
3. Move the loop cuts close together, or not so close for the thing at top. (Mark one loop with `ALT+Click` and move with `G`.
   [image]
4. Extrude then scale these faces (`E` then `S`) [image]
5. Now select some vertices first at top and scale to 0 (`S`then `Y`then `0`). Make sure you mark all the vertices (at top and bottom layer oder the paddle) [image]
6. Move these vertices as it is seems right. (`G`, then `Y`).
7. Do the same with the vertices on the other side (or delete half of the mesh and use the mirror modifier). [image]
8. Now move the outer vertices at the z-axis with proportional editing activated (`O` and `SHIFT + O` for mode selection). [image]. You can also scale on the x-axis to make them closer to the cylinder. You can also scale the top ring of the paddle in a similar way to achieve a look closer to the model you presented.
9. Use the subdivision surface modifier on the mesh. To avoid strange behaviour at top and bottom of the cylinder, add a loop cut close to the top and bottom.
10. Play around with the exact positions.
11. The top paddle is thicker as the others, but it should be possible with the same techniques.

[image]

My final result looks at least similar to the one you showed:

[image]

This should give you one possible idea for the mesh.

Comment: Does this answer your question appropriately?

Comment: thank you so much god bless you.. that should do it..